# Percentage - Two numbers relation question.

Tags: percentages

When 40% of a number A is added to another number B, B becomes 125% of is previous value. Then which of the following is true regarding the values of A and B? 
(a) A > B
(b) B > A
(c) B =A
(d) Either (a) or (b) can be true depending upon the values of A and B.

Comment: I would say that the equation is $0.4A+B=1.25B$. Now solve the equation for $A$ or $B$

Answer (score 1):

For such a question, it is useful to write down what we have in a mathematical way:
\begin{equation}
0.4A + B = 1.25B 
\end{equation}
Now, by subtracting $B$ on both sides, 
\begin{equation}
0.4A = 0.25B 
\end{equation}
Now, as $B = 1.6A$, it must be clear what the answer should be

Comment: Note the odd case, when B=A=0.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Although it is a pretty trivial case, it should not be excluded.

Comment: What if numbers are negative..? I think it will show A is greater than B. Right?

Comment: Don't think so, but that is depending on the context! It depends on what they mean. Consider both A, B to be negative. For instance, let $A = -100, B=-50$. Then, $40\%$ of $A$ is still negative 40 $(-40)$. Then, when you add that to something, it will become smaller $(-100-40=-140)$.

Comment: Concluding: in the general context, the answer stated above is a correct one, for both positive and negative numbers. You can check that by substituting some values in order to see that it works. However, it depends on the formulation interpretation